# Sorting a member data through an array which points to the base-class

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I've a **base class** (namely Laptop) with four **Private member data** and a bunch of **Public member functions** on the other hand there are **three derived classes** (namely Apple, Sony and IBM) without any further member data or function . Long story short, I'm using a **heterogeneous list** to point to the base class , I need to sort (bubble sort) one of the specific member data (namely cpuPower) of the derived classes by calling **virtual function** GetcpuPower of the base class. My question is how can I change the object's order in the array to sort them ?
As it's mentioned above, the sorting algorithm is bubble sort and one of the approaches to do this is by using an auxiliary function **Swap** to change the element's order in ascending or descending, I don't know how to do swaping in this particular example .

Comment: *"I'm using a heterogeneous list"*; *"in the array"* - which is it, list or array? Please post your code.

Comment: If it's a heterogeneous collection it must contain pointers, and pointers are trivially swappable. If it doesn't contain pointers it's homogeneous, containing only instances of the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown any code, and you are ambiguous about which container you are using, but you probably want something like this:

```
#include <vector> // Or whatever container you're using
#include <algorithm> // Or whatever swap function you're using

std::vector<Laptop*> foo;

// ...

// A single bubble sort pass:

for (int i = 0; i < foo.size() - 1; i++)
{
   // Modify if you want to change the sort order:
   if (foo[i]->GetcpuPower() > foo[i + 1]->GetcpuPower())
   {
      std::swap(foo[i], foo[i + 1]);
   }
}

// rest of bubble sort code
```